# Show that sequence $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...+\sqrt{2}}}$ is equal to $2 \, \cos(\theta)$

Tags: trigonometry, nested-radicals

Basicly the title. The profesor gave me the indication $1+\cos(a) = 2 \, \cos²\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)$

I have to verify that the sequence can be written as that trigonometric fonction. Teta is between [0,pi/2]

Comment: What is $\theta$ supposed to be equal to?  Are we supposed to solve for theta?

Comment: I have to verify that the sequence is equai to that trigonometric function and {/teta} is included in [0,pi/2]

Comment: Please specify what you really want.

Comment: The sequence doesn't have a variable so if it is equal to a function it must be a constant function.  That trig function isn't a constant function.  Do you mean that a = the sequence if that trig *equation* is true?

Comment: You must be forgetting to write something on the left side of the equation.

Comment: Well.. I'll try to write the whole question. It is a traduction so be patient =)
We have the quantity Un= \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...+\sqrt{2}}} with n /in  N* radicals.

1. Verify that we can write Un=2.cos(\teta n), \teta n \in {0,pi/2} to precise. Hint(1+cos(\alpha) = 2.cos²(\alpha/2)

Comment: The nested radical is a constant but the right-hand side is a function of $\theta$. You see how that's a problem don't you?

Comment: I understand that but I thought that that the "deepness" of the radical depends on n.. for exemple n=1 we have sqrt(2) for n=2 we have sqrt(2+sqr(2)) etc..

Comment: It does depend on $n$. So the left side depends on $n$ but has no $\theta$, whereas the right side depends on $\theta$ but has no $n$. Right? So what's going on here?

Comment: Yes the right side is 2*cos(\theta_n), \theta_n \in {0,pi/2}

Comment: So now there's a theta_n? I don't see any subscript in your question, and there's still no theta or theta_n on the left side of the equation. Many of us have downvoted and subsequently closed your question. You've had repeated opportunities to clarify and fix your question so as to be understood, but you have not done so. If you do fix it, then we can reopen and upvote it. The leading candidate for an interpretation of your question, given by N.S. is that $\theta$ is defined so that $\sqrt{2}=2\cos\theta$ and you are trying to prove the nested radical equals $2\cos(\theta/2^n)$.

Comment: In the future, please keep in mind: the difference between you giving us the question *clearly* and *accurately* is relatively minor and trivial difference in effort on your part - simply a few keystrokes makes all the difference - but us reading your *mind* takes a lot more from your readers than simply reading your question. It is rude to expect mind-reading from your readers.

Comment: You're right.. This is my first time here and I'm sorry. BTW I found the answer. It is 2 cos(pi/2^(n+1)). And thank everyone for their help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**
$$1+\cos(a) = 2 \, \cos²\left(\frac{a}{2}\right) \Rightarrow \\
2+2\cos(a) = 4 \, \cos²\left(\frac{a}{2}\right) \Rightarrow \\
\sqrt{2+ 2\cos(a)} =2 \cos(\frac{a}{2})$$

This means that if you start with 
$$\sqrt{2}=2 \cos(\theta_1)$$
by induction you get 
$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...+\sqrt{2}}}=\sqrt{2+2\cos(\frac{\theta_1}{2^{n-1}})}=2\cos(\frac{\theta_1}{2^n})$$
where there are $n$ roots on the LHS.

What is $\theta_1$?

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + ...}} = 2\cos\theta$

$\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + ...}}^2 = 4\cos^2\theta$

$2 + \sqrt{2 + ...} = 4\cos^2\theta$

$\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + ...}} = 4\cos^2\theta -2$

$2cos \theta = 4\cos^2\theta - 2$

$4 \cos^2 \theta - 2\cos \theta - 2 = 0$

$2\cos^2 \theta - \cos \theta - 1 = 0$

$(2\cos \theta + 1) (\cos \theta - 1) = 0$

$\cos \theta = \{1, -1/2\}$

$theta = \{0, 2\pi/3\}$

Comment: Thank you, it clarifies things but I have to find that  \theta ={0, pi/2] and not  [0,2pi/3]

Comment: You misunderstood the question as well as I did. The expression is not infinite but is actually finite. And the hint by professor in OP shows N.S.'s solution is the right way to intepret the question.

Comment: $\theta$ can't be $\pi/2$ because $\cos(\pi/2) = 0$. Therefore, your only solution is $\theta = 0$.